# What is the meaning of 杂院?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

但也有多户合住一座四合院的情况，被称为“大杂院”，住户多为普通劳动人民。

I found this in the Standard Course Book of HSK5, section 14.

What is the meaning of 杂院? According to dictionaries (character by character), it means "mixed courtyard", but I don't know, it does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This 知乎 thread](https://www.zhihu.com/question/24247987) sheds some light on the question.

大杂院 is a single word and you don't split it as "a big 杂院". 大 refers to its scale, housing multiple or even tens of families in one courtyard. 杂 (mixed, mingled) refers to its residents who aren't a single, large family and sometimes are even unrelated families, like modern residential areas. This is emphasized in comparison to traditional 四合院 where only one family resides.